# Using JSON file as database in a ASP.NET App(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, sql-server

I am developing a light weight web app in ASP.NET with C# and I would like to store some data such as site analytics etc.

Instead of using a SQL server database could I use a JSON file instead? So I would open the JSON file and write into it when done. Could there be problems with simultaneous connection?

Is this standard/ common practice?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Totally opinion based - "can I implement ACID DB over JSON file at my skill level" - how would we know?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a VERY bad idea. I would only do this if it was some text file to display a wee bit of information.

If you need updating? Then what happens if two users are on the site. The last person to update will over write the text based json file.

I suppose you could write out a "id" and json file for each record you edit, and that way a save of one record value would not over write others. But, putting more then one reocrd in a json file, and if users are to edit such values, then no, it will not work, since a simple save of that text json file will overwrite any other changes made by any other user who also happens to hit the same button.

It is VERY hard to find a web site hosting, even those for super cheap - less then $10 per month that does not include a database server system. And be it MySQL, SQL server, postgres sql and more? They all have free verisons you can use.

And I suppose you could consider the file based sqlLite. That would even be better. While it not considered thread safe, it can work if you only say have a a few users like 2-4 users working at the same time.

Because you have OH SO MANY choices here? The only reason to use a text based json file is if no other options exist - and boatloads of options exist in near all cases.

And if some database was not available? The I would simple include sqlLite in the project and use that.

Comment: Side note: you really should not be making opposite statements in single post - you claim that it is impossible to properly update file with multiple writes ("If you need updating? Then what happens if two users are on the site. The last person to update will over write the text based json file.") and yet suggest SQLite which does exactly that... (I totally agree that using JSON as storage is bad idea for real world usage as reliable implementations are easily available, but it is a good exercise in concurrent programming for which it is  a good idea)

Comment: More than one user can update sqlite, and a single row save does not write out the whole table (as opposed to a single JSON file). So yes you can do this. If sqlite was file based and also say like excel or a text file, then you couldn't do this. Not really different than using ms-access data engine. Again for light updates it can be used where as say Excel can't due to excel or text files being whole file based as opposed to being able to update only parts of the file like sqlite, access or even SQL server for that matter. Any system able to update 1 row as opposed to whole file can work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super experienced but i would like to explain why i would never do that.

First of all everything (if you are brave enough) can be a database, as long as it is some kind of file that can give persistency to your data. Database are basically optimized one purpose software to store data. Mainly the problem in your solution is that you would need to read the file and load it in memory storing it as an object and then writing data to it like you would do with a static factory object and then serialise it back to JSON after you are don with it. Personally i don't like this idea because i think is very prone to human error (like deleting the file by accident during mantainance) and it can be hard-er to debug if it starts accumulating a sizeable chunk of data. There are very lightweight data persistency solutions that implements SQLite that is a database for small applications, like Pocket Base. Since you are already developing a backend it would require you near to no effort to add a little table to store the analytics.